# Pick value in dropdown menu using VBA web scrape

Tags: java, excel, vba, web-scraping

I've got an issue trying to select items from a dropdown menu on a javascript webpage. My end goal is to fill in the menu value via a userform but I'm not having any success creating the VB to select the drop down. Web code is below

```
<select name="dateSelector0" class="clsInputArea selectBox valid" style="display: none; "onchange="setDateRange(this, 'rtf[0].val1', 'rtf[0].val2')">
   <option value="-1"></option>
   <option value="1">Last Month</option>
   <option value="2">Current Month</option>
   <option value="3">Next Month</option>
   <option value="4">Last Year</option>
   <option value="5">Current Year</option>
   <option value="6">Next Year</option>
   <option value="7">First Quarter</option>
   <option value="8">Second Quarter</option>
   <option value="9">Third Quarter</option>
   <option value="10">Fourth Quarter </option></select>

<a tabindex="NaN" title="" class="selectBox clsInputArea selectBox-dropdown" style="width: 147px; display: inline-block;" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 127px;">&nbsp;</span><span class="selectBox-arrow"></span></a>
```

I've tried various GetElementsBy, with both the above name, trying the below with the name and with ID rtf[0].val1 but to no avail, example below. I believe going by the dateSelector0 name will be best, but I would greatly appreciate input from those of you better at this than me.

```
ie.Document.Body.GetElementsByname("dateSelector0").Value = "1"
ie.Document.Body.GetElementsByname("dateSelector0").Item(0).FireEvent ("onchange")
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. I just tried:

```
Sub IE_Navigate()

'Declare
Dim IE As Object

'Use IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate ("Website URL")

'Wait for Load to finish
While IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

Both of these approaches worked for me. 
Select data from dropmenu by ClassName:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("clsInputArea")(0).Value = 1
```

Or 
Select data from dropmenu by Name

```
IE.document.getElementsByName("dateSelector0")(0).Value = 1
```

Which returned the first item from the drop down menu.

EDITED

Comment: Thanks Hubvill! however it's not working on my end. I'm using IE 11, do you think that's an issue? I tried both with and w/o the fireevent onchange line.

Comment: I am using IE 9, but I would check other things before changing your IE version. Do you have code to check if the webpage as finished loading? For example: 'Wait for Load to finish
While IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

Comment: You also need to check if their are any other name="dateSelector0" in the source code. getElementsByName("dateSelector0")(0) will only find the first tag containing that name. So for example if there are 2 drop down menus that have the name="dateSelector0" and you want to enter data into the second dropdown menu then use getElementsByName("dateSelector0")(1).value = 1

Comment: yes, I had do while ie.busy do events loop, I tried changing it to readystate <> 4 and it's now giving me a run-time 438 error: object doesn't support this property or method at the fireevent line

Comment: there is a dateselector1 as well, however I am intending on filling them both out. The first date dropdown is dateselector0 and what I've been trying to get working before I move to the other fields, as I figure it will be very similar coding and just modifying the name/id

Comment: Ah, this is difficult without seeing all of the html code. Are you able to post a link to the website or does that break some rules?

Comment: it's blocked by a log in and has sensitive business information. I will try and find some more relevant code sections if there's some key words or sections that would be helpful

Comment: Edited answer post let me know if getElementsByClassName works for you.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either. I've decided to sidestep the issue and go about it differently. Thank you so much for you time spent helping though! A true hero of the people.

Comment: Ah, dang. Sorry we couldn't get it working on your end. Best of luck on your next approach. ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the following CSS selector, where ["." means class](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) and [" option"](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) means select all "option" tags inside elements of that class (`clsInputArea selectBox valid`), you will see it makes the correct selections.

Note: You aren't allowed compound names in CSS selectors which is why the spaces are replaced with "." in the class name.

**Sample CSS query results:**

[image: Sample results]

---

**VBA:**

Now, we can translate that into the following syntax:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("clsInputArea selectBox valid")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
```

This assumes that index 0 is the correct one to use for elements of the class "select_list". You can easily inspect the collection to find the right index if you set it to a variable e.g.

```
Dim x As Object
Set x = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("clsInputArea selectBox valid")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
```

Assuming the object is not nothing then we can either select an option by its index (i.e. position) or by looping the collection and selecting when a certain condition is met e.g. its innerText matches a wanted phrase.

**Selecting by Index:**

This means for you you might say

`x.SelectedIndex = 1`  to select `Last Month`

**Selecting by looping:**

```
Dim currentOption As Object
For Each currentOption In x
    If InStr(currentOption.innerText, "Last Month") > 0 Then
        currentOption.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next currentOption
```

---

**Full example of selecting drop down:**

As you don't supply an URL, here is an example using a different website. The webpage target drop down, `Código de Ativo`, is shown here:

[image: Target dropdown]

The target option to select is `AALR21`, which is number 3, or **item 2** on 0 based index.

Looping and matching on the item innertext `AAL21`:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelectiong()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Const URL = "http://www.debentures.com.br/exploreosnd/consultaadados/sndemumclique/"
    Const optionText As String = "AALR21"        'Number2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False           '   a.selectedIndex = 2

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim a As Object, currentOption As Object
        Set a = .document.getElementById("ctl00_ddlAti")

        For Each currentOption In a.getElementsByTagName("Option")
            If InStr(currentOption.innerText, optionText) > 0 Then
                currentOption.Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next currentOption
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Selecting by index:

I could remove the entire loop and simply say:

```
a.selectedIndex = 2
```